# How to use a new img generated in a canvas, in another canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I use a canvas for cropping a jpg, i wish use this cropped img in another canvas

/**************CANVAS cropping img  *********/

```
  var canvas1 = document.getElementById('Canvas1');
  var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();

  imageObj.onload = function() {
    // draw cropped image
    var sourceX = 90;
    var sourceY = 0;
    var sourceWidth = 319;
    var sourceHeight = 319;
    var destWidth = sourceWidth;
    var destHeight = sourceHeight;
    var destX = canvas1.width / 2 - destWidth / 2;
    var destY = canvas1.height / 2 - destHeight / 2;

    context1.drawImage(imageObj, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'OriginImg.jpg';
```

/**************CANVAS using cropping img  *********/

```
  var canvas2 = document.getElementById('Canvas2');
  var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = canvas1;
  context2.drawImage(img, 10,10);
```

Comment: i need know how use the first canvas in img.src of the second canvas

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the standard way of drawing a canvas onto another one, and is discouraged, but if you want to use this method, you can always turn the first canvas into it's `dataURL` and use that as the src:

`img.src = canvas1.toDataURL()` will work just fine for you.

Check out the mdn page for [.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL).

The standard method would be to simply draw one of the canvases on the other:

`ctx2.drawImage( canvas1, 0, 0 )`

More information can be found in the mdn page for [.drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)